# Grep: How to search for an exact string of numbers in a file

Tags: command-line, grep

So I have a file 2k6d.pqr with a list of coordinates and I am trying to find one particular one.

I type in

`grep "-6.139  0.0488 1.4870" 2k6d.pqr`

and it returns an error:

```
grep: invalid option -- '.'
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERNS [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
```

I get no error with `grep --help` so it isn't with the grep installation or path. So I'm doing something wrong. I tried it with both -w and -x and it didn't work. What do I do?

Comment: Use `grep -e "-6.139  0.0488 1.4870" 2k6d.pqr` (maybe also add the `-F` option)